# Are there examples of African/European/American hunter-gatherer's constructions?

Tags: archaeology, prehistory, construction, paleolithic, aboriginals

Often people think about hunter-gatherers as primitives. "Dark Emu" book is a great example of popular history book that refutes those beliefs. Aboriginal constructions could be quite impressive: Brewarrina - 1800 meters of dams for fishery, Toolondo 1200 m channel, Condah eel traps - 2 km of channels, Bulloo water storage dam that stored 700 m^3 of water during arid season, 7 m deep water wells caved in stone.

"Dark Emu" concentrates on Australia. What about the rest of the world?

I found some info about Comox Harbour(Canada) or Iijoki River(Finland) fish traps but they look much less impressive than Brewarrina Complex.

What are examples of African/European/American hunter-gatherer's record sizes for dams, canals, wells?

Comment: That is a huge scope for a list question - how will you select an authoritative answer?

Comment: If you want impressive constructions by hunter-gatherers, the tribes of the Pacific Northwest coast built a rather impressive civilization -- when the food comes to you, rather than you chasing the food, you've got plenty of spare time to do things.

Comment: `Are there equally impressive examples of African/European/American hunter-gatherer's constructions?` It'll be best if you can narrow down this criteria for a bit, and perhaps offer a definition for "impressive" since that feels subjective. Physical scale perhaps? You could ask for the biggest hunter-gather construction outside of Brewarrina.

Comment: There are those that would argue that the Australian Aboriginal weirs by definition rendered the builders *not* hunter-gatherers.

Comment: For North America, there's Alta Toquima, a village built on top of a 3300 m mountain range in the middle of a desert: http://digitaleditions.sheridan.com/publication/?i=210655&article_id=1716728&view=articleBrowser&ver=html5